# 19 FOREIGN KEY constraint failed on Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, sqlite

I'm trying to write data to my SQLite database. I think there's an error at my migration file and the foreign keys.

I have tried to change names of the files, making the foreign key nullable and clearing Laravel's caches.

Are you familiar with the error that the error handler shows or could you point me towards a page that could help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

Migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSqrTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sqrs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable(); 
            $table->string('qr_link');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade'); 
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('sqr');
    }
}
```

Model file:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

// sQR stands for Saved QR-Code


class sqr extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'qr_link', 'user_id'
    ];
}
```

Controller that saves:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\sqr;

class saveController extends Controller
{
    public function save(Request $request)
    {
        $sqr = new sqr;
        $sqr->qr_link =     $request->qr_link;
        $sqr->user_id =     1;
        $sqr->save();

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

front end blade file:

```
<form method="post" action="/save">
        @csrf
       <input type="hidden" name="qr_link" value="{{ session('url') }}">
       <button class="btn btn-success">Save this QR</button>
    </form>
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (SQL: insert into "sqrs" ("qr_link", "user_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (images/1567444499.svg, 1, 2019-09-02 17:37:23, 2019-09-02 17:37:23))
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have an User with id = 1 in the database?

Comment: @dparoli Oops.... Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @S-o  What does that mean?  If that fixed the problem, then this question is likely no help to anyone else and should be deleted.  You can do that yourself.  Otherwise, elaborate on what you mean by "Oops".

Comment: This was the answer to my question. I can't give him a star because it's a common t.

Comment: You can write your own answer and mark it as accepted. Very helpful for those  who search for unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dparoli said in a comment of this post:

"Are you sure that you have an User with id = 1 in the database? – dparoli"

This was the answer to my question. Because there was nog user = 1 in the database, it crashed.